# Where are YouTube messages sent?

Tags: youtube, youtube-studio

On the **About** page of some YouTube channels there's a "Send message" button for contacting them through private message. As an example, [here's the about page from my channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/stevoisiak/about).

[image: My channel's 'about' page]

**Where are these messages sent to? How can I check if I've received a message?**

I know that YouTube used to have a private messaging system, but that was years ago. I haven't been able to find a message inbox in the current version of YouTube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/messages is the page you are looking for. You can reach it via the avatar menu > creator studio > community > messages from anywhere at YouTube.